# How to read from syslog?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

I can write to syslog via:

```
logger "foo bar baz"
```

but how do I read from syslog? my only guess is:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

but that doesn't seem right from my testing.

Note: also looking for a way to delete/drain all syslog logs/messages.

Comment: There is a nice wrapper script over tail called `logread` https://github.com/rs/openwrt-packages/blob/master/admin/syslog-ng/files/logread
This is the only "reader" that I found

Answer (score 1):

tail -f shows what happens after it is run, so you need to start that command before issuing the logger command.

Syslog is just a text file. so you can read it with anything that handles those - less is often used. (You can also grep or otherwise manipulate its output to look for certain things)

It is possible that the logging us not going to syslog - look at /var/log/messages, and if that does not work look at /etc/rsyslog* to track where logging is going.